# How to create a DatePicker in the PDF form using iTextSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, datepicker, itext

How to create a `DatePicker` in the PDF form using `iTextSharp`? I know it's not supported by default. But Adobe Acrobat can implement this functionality (maybe, it uses JS).
How can I add all same field type or a similar in my PDF using iTextSharp? Appearance hasn't value, the main purpose is a validation of a date value.

Comment: It definitely uses js. Thus, you merely have to find that js code and then simply embed it using itext.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote own validator using js.

Comment: Does that validator include visualisation as a date picker?

Comment: No, I don't know how to make it. Just it sets fields to default value if the user made a some issue.

Comment: Then you should look for such js. Your question is only tagged  [tag:datepicker] and [tag:itext] but nothing js'ish or generically pdf'ish. The only role itext has here is to inject js, but the js itself is not itext'ish.

Comment: Yeah, I really forgot to add them. Thank you! I updated tags.